# Use PowerBi to create table with specific format

Tags: powerbi

I'm using PowerBi to connect from a Redcap database (using API) to an Oncore database.  Specifically what I'm doing is:

- New users fill out details about themselves in the Redcap.  Name/email stuff like that.
- Power Bi connects to that and reorganizes the latest data I ask for into columns I will need to do the "data import" into Oncore.  Looks like this  (all fake names and emails):

[image]

- I then export those tables visible right there as csv's and import them into Oncore. For the contacts themselves (top table), works great. (I need multiple rows like that, long story)

**Here's my problem:**

- To import the access group stuff (second table), I cant have an Organizational Unit on the same row as a department.  And the "Access Control" must be on the row with the department, NOT on the other row.  Also I cant just simply erase it from certain rows, instead itd be more useful to double all the rows.

Expected output:

[image]

Is this possible in PowerBi?  If so, can I do it without altering my original query?

Comment: You want to remove the "Access Control" from rows with a "Research Groups"?

Comment: Yes, but this is after "duplicating" all of the rows in the first place, and alternating which rows get "research groups"